# System.OutOfMemoryException when creating brush from image byte array

Tags: .net, drawing, gdi+

I sometimes need to load an image from a byte array like this:

```
Bitmap image = null;

using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(sourceImagePath)))
{
    image = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Now I need to create a `TextureBrush` from that image, so I use the following approach:

```
using (var b = new TextureBrush(image))
{

}
```

It throws `System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Out of memory.'`. After a while of experimenting, I've found that I can create the brush if I use `Image.FromFile` like this:

```
using (var b = new TextureBrush(Image.FromFile(sourceImagePath)))
{

}
```

For brevity, I will not go into the reason why I do not want to use this method, so can anyone show me how I can use the byte array approach in the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the using statement on the MemoryStream.

1) A MemoryStream does not take up any system resources, so there is no need disposing them. You just close the stream.

2) When you use Image.FromStream you must leave the stream open. See the remarks section on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=netframework-4.7.2:

> **Remarks**
>
> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

Another alternative would be to copy the bitmap, like so:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(sourceImagePath)))
using (var bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms))
{
    image = new Bitmap(bmp);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I never would have thought to make a copy of the streamed bitmap as in your last example. It works well, so I will use it. I am glad that option exists because I do not like using `IDisposable` objects without `using`. They may not use system resources or require clean-up now, but, if that ever changes in the future, you can rest assured you will not need to refactor any of that code.

Comment: Glad I could help.